# How to prove set $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2~\vert~y>x^2\}$ is open (I need some hints)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Q: Prove $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2~\vert~y>x^2\}$ is in open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

One of my intuitions:
$S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2~\vert~y>x^2\}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2~\vert~y-x^2>0\}$
Define $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=y-x^2$.
Then $f$ is continuous and $S=f^{-1}((0,+\infty))$.
Since $(0,+\infty)$ is open, $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2~\vert~y>x^2\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Can anyone tell me whether this proof is valid or not? I'm not sure about the set $(0,+\infty)$ being open.
If someone know how to prove this by open ball $B((a,b),r)$ for $(a,b)\in S$, pray tell.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: Shouldn't $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \ | \ y >x^{2}\}$??

Comment: Sure.  I'll make the edit.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out and the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems fine.  To prove this the $\varepsilon$-ball way, let $A = \{ (x,y) : y = x^2 \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.  Then let $(a,b) \in S$.  Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2} \inf \{ d((a,b),(c,d)) : (c,d) \in A \}$.  This $\varepsilon$ should do the job.

Comment: Do you mean by taking $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2} min\{d(a,b),d(c,d)\}$ where $(c,d)\in A$? But what's $(c,d)$. I'm little lost.

Comment: I don't know why you need the Infimum?

Comment: Inf actually makes sense in this case.  There are an infinite number of choices, in general we don't always get the inf to be the min... here we do.  Its not a big deal either way.

Comment: Still a little confused, but I think I got the idea, thanks.

Comment: The definition of the distance between a point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is $d((a,b),A) = \inf \{ d((a,b),(c,d)) : (c,d) \in A \}$.  In other words, take the distance from $(a,b)$ to each point $(c,d)$ in $A$, and take the infimum over all those distances.  This gives you the "shortest" distance between $(a,b)$ and the parabola $y = x^2$.

Comment: Since both the point and the set $A$ are closed sets, then this distance must be nonzero.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems all right. $(0, \infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, because if $x \in (0,\infty)$ then let $\epsilon = \frac{x}{2}$ then clearly $(x-\varepsilon , x+ \varepsilon) \subset (0,\infty)$.

Comment: But how to show $(0,\infty)$ is open?

Comment: Someone actually downvoted this?  It was very good

Comment: I see, Thanks for the answer. Totally agree on why someone would downvote this.